# Undefined variable: term

Tags: php, laravel

I am triying to make a search bar with 2 different tables.I have a error message:
**Undefined variable: term**

```
public function index(Request $req){

     if($req->search == ""){
            $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
           return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
     } else {
          $feedbacks = feedback::whereHas('candidats', function($query) use($term){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
     });  

      }

    }
```

Do you have an idea please? I am really stuck.

Regards

Edit: for information

Table Feedbacks: 
id, instruction, description, fk_candidat

Table Candidats
id, name, firstname

Comment: `$term` does not exist in this functions scope

Comment: You're using the variable `$term` but it isn't defined in your code. Where are you meant to be getting `$term` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are use `use($term) {` but `$term` not defined yet

```
if($req->search == ""){
        $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
       return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
 } else {
      $term = $req->search; 
      $feedbacks = feedback::whereHas('candidats', function($query) use($term){
      $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
      return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
 });
```

But for more good code experience

```
public function index(Request $req) 
{
    if ($req->search == "") {
        $feedbacks = Feedback::paginate(5);
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
    } 

    $feedbacks = feedback::whereHas('candidats', function($query) use($req) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $req->search . '%');
        })->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'))
}
```

Comment: I would suggest passing the `$req` variable rather than creating another variable for no real benefit.

Comment: @RossWilson I try make small changes on initial code

Comment: That's a nice, clean answer :)

Comment: @Davit: Thank you a lot Davit, my problem is solve... You are the best !!! :-) Thank you very much.